# How to loop dictionary with multiple values in Jinja?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have a dictionary like so: `{'a': [Object, 0], 'b': [Object, 1] }` Where object is an actual object with multiple attributes. I'm trying to a check on each key to see if the second value in the array is a 0 or 1. If it is a 1, then I'll display "Hello" if it's a 0, I'll display "Goodbye" Here's what I have so far that doesn't seem to work:

```
{% for key in follower_list %}
   {% if follower_list[key][1] == 0 %}
        <p>Hello</p>
   {% else %}
         <p>Goodbye</p>
{% endif %}
```

Here, follower_list is the dictionary. I'm getting an error by my IDE saying operator expected where `follower_list[key][1]` is there a way I can do this type of logic in Jinja?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `iteritems` to iterate through your dictionary:

```
{% for key, value in follower_list.items %}
    {% if value.1 == 0 %}
        <p>Hello</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>Goodbye</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Check this [docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#for).

Comment: Hmm, in `my_dict.iteritems()` I get a could not parse the remainder: () from `my_dict.iteritems()`

Comment: Are you sure you're using second version of Jinja?

Comment: @user2896120 check my update. Maybe you just using django templates.

Comment: I'm using Jinja2, but yes that works. However, the next issue is with `value[1]`  it says: Could not parse the remainder: '[1]' from 'value[1]'

Comment: @user2896120 updated. Check your project TEMPLATES setting in `settings.py`.  Guess you have `'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates'`. I'm totally sure that you using django templates instead of Jinja2. If you want to switch to Jinja2 set `'Backend'` to `django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2` and use my first solution.

Comment: That worked, but what does the templates setting have to do with anything?

Comment: By default it's `DjangoTemplates`:) Check this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/).

Comment: I see, is it better to use Jinja or the default DjangoTemplates?

Comment: I prefer Jinja2. It provides more flexibility and speed. You can read about it in the [project's main page](http://jinja.pocoo.org).

Comment: Hmm, is there an easy way to switch from django templates to jinja2?

Comment: It's quite easy to switch to Jinja2, it was created under great influence of Django's templating system so they have quite similar syntax logic (but you as you can see, they also different). In conclusion, if your project not vert large at this moment, I recommend you to switch to Jinja2.

Comment: Yes, it's still small. But what are the steps to switch over? Do I just change the backend engine?

Comment: Yep. Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/#configuration) paragraph. Of course you need to install jinja2.

Answer (score 6):

Try using this method:

```
{% for key, value in follower_list.items() %}
    {% key %}
    {% value %}
{% endfor %}
```

This calls the items function on the dictionary letting you iterate through all the keys and values of the dictionary.

Comment: Hmm, in follower_list.items() I get a could not parse the remainder: () from follower_list.items()

Comment: TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'key'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endfor' Got this error

Comment: @AnshumanKumar Jinja requires and endfor tag for for loops, Ive updated the snippet to include that implied code