# Cannot retrieve data from my flask CRUD application from mysql table even though its getting inserted without any error

Tags: html, python-3.x, forms, flask, flask-mysql

Here's the python snippet

```
@app.route('/oxygenadmin')
@is_logged_in
def oxygenadmin():
    cur=mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM oxygen")
    data =cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    return render_template('oxygenadmin.html', oxygen=data)
    



@app.route('/insert', methods=['POST'])
@is_logged_in
def insert():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        contact = request.form['contact']
        email = request.form['email']
        place = request.form['place']

        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO oxygen(name, contact, email, place) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",(name,contact,email,place))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        flash("Data inserted successfully", 'success')
        return redirect (url_for('oxygenadmin'))
    return render_template ('oxygenadmin.html')
```

And here's the html snippet

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col md-12">
                <h2> Oxygen Details <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">Enter New Data</button> </h2>

                <table class="table table-striped">
                    
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Contact No.</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Place</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                {% for row in oxygen %}
                
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{row.0}}</td>
                        <td>{{row.1}}</td>
                        <td>{{row.2}}</td>
                        <td>{{row.3}}</td>
                        <td>{{row.4}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaledit">Edit</a>
                            <a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Delete</a>


                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and...

```
<div id="mymodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Please insert data!</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form action="{{url_for('insert')}}" method="POST">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required='1'>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Contact No. :</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact" required='1'>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Place</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="place" required='1'>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Insert Data</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I somehow just cant get it to appear on my page

Here's how it looks
[in the website itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd2U6.png)

But it's getting inserted in the actual database though
[Didnt paste the entire picture because there are some personal details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7JzX.png)

The table name is **oxygen**, I probably think it's doing something with the name itself , I just cant get it

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51813619/10753968) help?

Comment: Thanks but I took care of it, should have posted the answer myself but got too excited since it started working, but yeah its basically within that loop
Instead of  `{{row.0}}` it would be `{{row["id"]}}` so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing this...

```
{% for row in oxygen %}
                
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{row.0}}</td>
                        <td>{{row.1}}</td>
                        <td>{{row.2}}</td>
                        <td>{{row.3}}</td>
                        <td>{{row.4}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaledit">Edit</a>
                            <a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Delete</a>


                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

to

```
{% for row in oxygen %}
                
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{row["id"]}}</td>
                        <td>{{row["name"]}}</td>
                        <td>{{row["contact"]}}</td>
                        <td>{{row["email"]}}</td>
                        <td>{{row["place"]}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaledit">Edit</a>
                            <a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Delete</a>


                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

solves the issue